# How to properly use rsync Push with SSH on local macOS to remote Debian

Tags: ssh, debian, mac-osx, rsync

I've been trying to get rsync working for a couple of hours now, but haven't had much luck .  I have a Digital Ocean droplet that I would like to send a file via rsync using SSH.

local rsync running on macOS 10.12.6 installed via homebrew
`rsync version 3.1.2 protocol version 31`

remote rsync running on Debian 8.x installed via apt
`rsync version 3.1.1 protocol version 31`

I am trying to send a single file from the local macOS box to the remote Debian box (Digital Ocean droplet)
The command I am issuing locally in Terminal on macOS
`$ rsync -avvvv -e "ssh -p $SSH_PORT_# -v" dummy $USER@example.com:/home/$USER/www/`

Some tidbits,
 
1) dummy is a single 10MB file on my local system.
2) I can successfully ssh in the remote Digital Ocean with the below command, $ ssh nathan
2.1) I have a "config" file in /Users/$USER/.ssh/ 
2.2) The contents of the /Users/$USER/.ssh/config

Host nathan 
HostName $REMOTE_IP_ADDRESS i.e. 1.2.3.4 
User $REMOTE_USERNAME chris 
port $SSH_PORT_# 4242 
IdentityFile /Users/$USER/.ssh/id_rsa

3) I can also ssh into the remote Digital Ocean droplet with the below command 
`$ ssh -l $USER -p 4242 $REMOTE_USERNAME example.com`

Some output from running the above rsync command, 
opening connection using: ssh -p 4242 -v -l $USER example.com rsync --server -vvvvlogDtpre.iLsfxC . /home/$USER/www/ (12 args) 
 
msg checking charset: UTF-8 
OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0 
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/$USER/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config 
debug1: Connecting to example.com [1.2.3.4] port 4242. 
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to example.com:4242 as '$USER'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC:  compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC:  compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:REMOVED_KEY
debug1: Host '[example.com]:4242' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/$USER/.ssh/known_hosts:15
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/$USER/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to example.com ([1.2.3.4]:4242).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: Sending command: rsync --server -vvvvlogDtpre.iLsfxC --log-format=%i . /home/$USER/www/
(Client) Protocol versions: remote=31, negotiated=31

And this is as far I can get using using the above rsync command  If you have any thoughts / suggestions I'd sure love ❤️ to hear them.

cheers  
Chris

Comment: @janos I put that there to omit the actual port that I am using, i.e. when i run the command on my local box (macOS) I specify the actual port I am using on the server with `-p 4242`.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Have you double checked permissions on the www folder? Sometimes, you can't write to a folder if the parent folders don't share common permissions; maybe try setting the path as ~/www/   instead of /home/$USER/www/

Comment: @AnsonWHan thanks for the heads up.

I have been hacking ⌨️ away at my `config.fish` for the past couple of days.  And needless to say I put some commands in there that ended up scp / rsync from properly working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR; The issue was related to my `config.fish` file.

How I ended up coming to a resolution.

I decided for a sanity check to create a new user on both machines and test rsync / scp with the newly created user account.  Low and behold both ended up working.

Things I ended up trying, rebooting the remote box, starting up sshd in single user mode by passing the `-vvvv` flag, sifting through the log and seeing nothing related to a file being sent improperly.

The only other computer I have access to locally is a RasPi, so I tried scp / rsync locally to the RasPi, which ended working, so I deduced it had to do something with a configuration file on the server.